# How to use Downloaded Bootstrap Template

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I am new to ASP.NET and have run through some tutorials. The next step for me was to find a really cool bootstrap template to employ. I downloaded this solution http://bootstraptaste.com/bocor-bootstrap-template-nice-animation/ and tried to change the .css file as I did originally following the Visual Studio tutorial http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#bootstrap .

Nothing happened. Also, a ton of files came with the template I downloaded, including an index.html file which actually loads the project into Internet Explorer.

[image]

[image]

I'd like to load this solution in Visual Studio so I can play around with it and modify it. Is this possible? I am definitely not advanced enough yet to get the same results on my own. Any advice and help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Visual Studio is the best tool for creating your websites. To get your template running, execute the file index.html in a web browser. It is however, a better practice to run your templates from a server like xampp, wamp or IIS (in case of Windows OS).

In case of xampp, copy the folder to xampp/htdocs/. Then start the xampp server and based upon the port your xampp server is running on, run it on a web browser by typing **localhost:port/folder_name** in the address bar.

The procedure is similar for wamp with the only difference being in the path. The path for wamp will be wamp/sites/

Comment: I'm actually building my solution in Visual Studio with ASP.NET and deploying to Azure as a web app. What i need to do is apply the template to a default Visual Studio web project.